# Invalid command line files

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xamarin.android

All the solutions posted here on stack overflow dont seem to suit my situation. I am using visual studio. How do I fix this error  while not ruining the setup for monotouch? Monotouch docs say explicity that I should not at all start the image but monodroid will do it.

I am using mono  for the android with visual studio. and soon will be using monotouch for IPhone

Comment: Can you provide more details about the problem you're having? I can't really tell from the description. Are you using Mono for Android or MonoTouch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get the `Invalid command-line option: Files`, you should do the following (just fixed it on my machine):

- Uninstall the Android SDK (if you have downloaded images, make a backup copy of the installation folder first)
- Install the Android SDK again, but make sure you install it to a path that does *not contain spaces*. `C:\Android` will work fine.
- After installation has finished, copy the backup copy over the newly installed version. Then you will keep your downloaded system images.

This apparently occurs because the Android SDK has a bug in the latest version when it comes to folders with spaces in them. Weird.

Comment: I just ran into this issue, thanks for saving me a lot of time.